# Pushing data from ROS2 robot to Mqtt broker

Tags: localization, mqtt, ros2

I want to send data from my robot which is running on ROS2 to Mqtt broker. I have 4 topics from which I want to send data from robot to Mqtt. Any idea how can I do that . My topics are (odometer,LiDAR,imusensor and localization). I am stuck and don’t know how to push data from my robot to Mqtt.

I want to push data from my robot to Mqtt.

Comment: What research into ROS MQTT clients have you done before asking? Asking for recommendations for libraries is considered off topic for Stack Overflow, but questions showing what you've tried and how it doesn't work will usually get help in fixing it.